# display on hover and rotate ticks 90 degrees at the same time in flot bar graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using flot and rendering a bar graph. I am having very big labels on my x-axis so I rotated them to 90 degrees using  https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor. 
But In my graph I am also using tooltip to show user the data on hover. When I am using both of them simultaneously I am getting the flowing error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined".
```

My code:

```
<script>
 var dataset = [{ data: data, color: "#5482FF" }];


        var options = {
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            bars: {
                align: "center",
                barWidth: 0.5
            },
            xaxis: {
                axisLabel: "EquipmentMainCatagory",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 10,
                ticks: ticks,
           rotateTicks:90
            },
            yaxis: {
                axisLabel: "# Assets",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 3,

            },

            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }
            }
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, options);
            $("#placeholder").UseTooltip();
        });

    var previousPoint = null, previousLabel = null;

            $.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
                $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                    if (item) {
                        if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
                            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
                            previousLabel = item.series.label;
                            $("#tooltip").remove();

                            var x = item.datapoint[0];
                            var y = item.datapoint[1];

                            var color = item.series.color;

                            //console.log(item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label);               

                            showTooltip(item.pageX,
                            item.pageY,
                            color,
                            item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>");
                        }
                    } else {
                        $("#tooltip").remove();
                        previousPoint = null;
                    }
                });
            };
        function showTooltip(x, y, color, contents) {
                $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    display: 'none',
                    top: y - 40,
                    left: x - 120,
                    border: '2px solid ' + color,
                    padding: '3px',
                    'font-size': '9px',
                    'border-radius': '5px',
                    'background-color': '#fff',
                    'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                    opacity: 0.9
                }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
            }
</script>
```

Comment: `xaxis: { ..., ticks: ticks, ... }` where does the second `ticks` come from? What does it look like?

Comment: The data I am fetching from a query and ticks array I took in Javascript. The code:                                                var data = "data in JSON from database";

var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ticks.push([i,data[i][0]]);
    data[i][0] = i;   
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `jquery.flot.tickrotor.js` plugin clears the `.ticks` array property and creates it's own `.rotatedTicks` array property.

So switch to:

```
item.series.xaxis.rotatedTicks[x].label
```

And all should be well.

Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C2ZPy/).

Answer (score 0):

In your `bind("plothover"...)` function, you use

```
item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>");
```

but your `ticks` array consists of arrays and not objects with a `label` property.
You can try replacing the above line with

```
item.series.xaxis.ticks[x][1] + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>");
```

Comment: This isn't true.  The `item.series.xaxis.ticks` should be an array of objects after flot processes them.  It looks like when the `tickrotor` plugin takes over, it fudges some things.  See my answer.

Comment: Ok, I was not familiar with the details of that plugin.